# Azure Manage Backups menu missing

Tags: azure

Im checking several tutorials about how to setup and configure a sql backup to blob, but what Ive found so far are to backup from Sql Server Management Studio.

I did found this nice article at azurelessons: https://azurelessons.com/backup-azure-sql-database/

But the problem I have is that they mention a "Manage Backups" option at the settings group (Sql server level) which I cannot seem to find:

[image]

And when I go to the Backups option on Data Management, it only shows me one that is 7 days old with the following legend: "Azure SQL databases are backed up automatically. Backup availability is listed below for each database on this server. Manage your available long-term retention (LTR) backups or restore a database here."

I have a failover group for the SQL server, but I would also like to have backups performed every 6 hours, and I just cant find the option where to do this, even on the SQL Database.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a managed instance of SQL

Both SQL Database and SQL Managed Instance use SQL Server technology to create full backups every week, differential backups every 12-24 hours, and transaction log backups every 5 to 10 minutes. The frequency of transaction log backups is based on the compute size and the amount of database activity.

When you restore a database, the service determines which full, differential, and transaction log backups need to be restored.

Please check this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database